# Minha função que retorna um booleano true/false caso exista ou não, está correta?

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo alguns exercícios de js e gostaria de saber se minha função está correta!

1) Escreva uma função que verifique se o vetor de habilidades passado possui a habilidade "Javascript" e retorna um booleano true/false caso exista ou não.

```js
function Habilidade(skill){
            if(skill == 'javascript'){
                console.log('Você sabe javascript');
            } else if(skill == 'reactjs'){
                console.log('Você sabe reactjs');
            } else if(skill == 'React native'){
                console.log('Você sabe React native');
            } else{
                console.log('Você não sabe nenhuma das linguagens');
            }
        }

        var resultado = Habilidade('javascript');
        var skill = ['javascript', 'reactjs', 'React native'];
```

Comment: Pela descrição do problema, a função não faz o que manda.

Comment: Sua função não recebe o array no seu exemplo, e mesmo se recebesse, não funcionaria do jeito certo, além do mais, não retorna uma valor booleano

Comment: Vai precisar fazer com que a função percorra todos os valores do array passado como parâmetro na função, com base nisso você compara se existe o valor, caso haja o valor solicitado, você retorna true, do contrário false

Comment: Denis você poderia me explicar de forma mais detalhada? Obrigado.

Comment: "Minha função está correta" - Poderia melhorar a sua pergunta, acrescentando parte da dúvida que está no conteúdo.

Comment: se você quer fazer um a mais pode usar regex e verificar se uma frase possui determinada palavra ou expressão

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Escreva uma função que verifique se o vetor de habilidades passado possui a habilidade "Javascript" e retorna um booleano true/false caso exista ou não?

Utilize [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) se o retorno for maior ou igual a 0 existe no `array` o valor procurado, ***exemplo***:

```js
function habilidade(skill, find) {
  return (skill.indexOf(find) >= 0);
}

var skill = ['javascript', 'reactjs', 'React native'];
var resultado = habilidade(skill, 'javascript');
console.log(resultado);
```

ou você pode percorrer esse `array`, ***exemplo***:

```js
function habilidade(skill, find) 
{
    var i = 0;
    while(i < skill.length)
    {
        if (skill[i] == find)
        {
            return true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return false;
}

var skill = ['javascript', 'reactjs', 'React native'];
var resultado = habilidade(skill, 'javascript');
console.log(resultado);
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz assim:

```
function temHabilidade(skills) {
 skills.forEach(item => console.log(item === "Javascript"))
}

var skills = ["Javascript", "ReactJS", "React Native"];
temHabilidade(skills); // true ou false
```

Answer (score 0):

**Outra maneira bem fácil tbm de se fazer:**

```js
function Habilidade(){
   
  if(skill.includes('javascript')) {
     console.log(true);
   } else {
     console.log(false);
   } 
}

var skill = ['javascript', 'reactjs', 'React native'];
var resultado = Habilidade();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Eu consegui fazer dessa forma

```
function temHabilidade(skills) {
        var resultado = skills.indexOf("Javascript");

        if (resultado >= 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    var skills = ["Javascript", "ReactJS", "React Native"];
  
    console.log(temHabilidade(skills));
```

Answer (score -1):

`<script>
        function temHabilidades(skills) {
            var skill;
            if (skills.indexOf('Javascript')) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        var skills = ['Javascript'];
        console.log(temHabilidades(skills));
    </script>`

Answer (score -3):

```
        function temHabilidade(skills) {

        var skill;
        if (skills.indexOf('Javascript')) {
            console.log(false);
        } else {
            console.log(true);
        }
    }
        var skills = ['Javascript'];
        temHabilidade(skills);
    </script>
```